# Tags without questions

Tags: discussion, tags

[us8320592](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us8320592), [ep0465662a1](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ep0465662a1), [page-turning](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-turning), [inequitable](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequitable) and [conduct](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conduct) have no questions tagged. Should they be removed? The latter two could be turned into synonyms, too.